# Trying to get property of non object in Yii model

Tags: php, object, yii

I have the following controller logic which returns a 'non object error'

This happens once I add the user second line.... any ideas?

```
$parentuser = new MyparentsMyuser::model()->findAll();
$parentuser->setAttributes(array(
    'user_id' => Yii::app()->controller->user->id,
    'parent_id' => 4259
));
```

Comment: It means `->controller` or `->user` or `->id` don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one of the golden rules of any development : check your result.

The first line in your code is expected to return either an array of models or an empty array.

```
// findAll() Returns an array of results.
// Wrong !! You are combining new and findall
// $parentuser = new MyparentsMyuser::model()->findAll();
$parentuser = MyparentsMyuser::model()->findAll();
```

Then, considering my comments about the expected return value, you usage on line 2 is invalid.

```
// Wrong!! You cannot apply the setAttributes() method to an array.
$parentuser->setAttributes( ...);
```

You therefore have to parse the array and apply the setAttributes to each element, if this is what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got this error because there are some typing mistake.

```
$parentuser = new MyparentsMyuser::model()->findAll();
```

replace to

```
$parentuser = MyparentsMyuser::model()->findAll();
```